# phaser 3 sprites with random x,y but in a specific area

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have some sprites in a group with random  x,y. and I want those x,y  be somewhere on my, let's say, ground area (which is a circle graphic object). What is the best way to do this?

I was thinking about something like this: in update check if the sprite x,y overlap (contains) with ground or not, if they do let them be if they don't destroy them and make an other random x,y and so on.

But since those sprites are too many and overlap area (ground) it's not that big it would effect on performance I guess(it will?).

So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What exactly are your limitations? Only that the sprites should be inside the circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the sprites to land randomly inside the circle, you can use polar coordinates.

[image: Polar and cartesian coordinates]

Let's say your "ground" circle is of radius R and its center is at M.

every point on the circle can be expressed as either an (x, y) pair or a (r, a) pair, where a is the angle and r is the distance from the center.

As seen in the image, you can get the (x, y) coordinates from the (r, a) coordinates using two formulae. In your case, the center is at M so the formulae need to be adjusted:

```
x = r * Math.cos(a) + M.x;
y = r * Math.sin(a) + M.y;
```

If you want to be precise, you can also account for the size of the sprites so that the (x, y) pair you get is the top left corner of the sprite:

```
x = r * Math.cos(a) + M.x - sprite.width / 2;
y = r * Math.sin(a) + M.y - sprite.height / 2;
```

Now all you have left is to randomly generate `r`, the distance from the center of the circle, and `a`, the angle from the X axis. You can get them using the following:

```
r = R * Math.random();
a = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
```

if you don't want the sprites to go over the edge of the circle, you can subtract the radius of the sprites, like this:

```
r = (R - sprite.radius) * Math.random();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate the explanation